# Как в моём плагине включить/отключить функцию?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Подскажите плиз. В плагине есть функция: при наведении мыши на слайд, слайдер останавливается. Как сделать что бы эту функцию можно было отключить/включить при вызове плагина ? Пробовал через переменную задавать, но что-то не выходит.

```js
(function($){
var settings = {
   sliderInterval: 2000,                              
    animateTime: 1000,                               
    course: 1,
    nextBtn: '.nextBtn',
  prevBtn: '.prevBtn',      
};  //объект с настройками 

$.fn.simpleSlider = function(options) {
 settings = $.extend(settings, options) // сливаем настройки которые передал пользователь со своим объектом

 return this.each(function(){  



  resized=false;
  var thisEl =$(this);
  slider = thisEl.children('div','ul','img'),
  slideWidth = thisEl.width(),
  slider_item = slider.children(),
  slideCount = slider_item.length,
  next = settings.nextBtn,
  prev = settings.prevBtn,   
    sliderInterval = settings.sliderInterval,                              // Интервал смены слайдов
    animateTime = settings.animateTime,                                 // Время смены слайдов
    course = settings.course,                                         // Направление движения слайдера (1 или -1)
    margin = - slideWidth;                              // Первоначальное смещение слайдов
 

  slider_item.css('width',slideWidth);
  slider_item.last().clone().prependTo(slider);   // Копия последнего слайда помещается в начало.
  slider_item.eq(0).clone().appendTo(slider);   // Копия первого слайда помещается в конец.  
  slider.css('margin-left', -slideWidth);         // Контейнер .slider сдвигается влево на ширину одного слайда.
  slider_item = slider.children();
 


  function nextSlide(){                                 // Запускается функция animation(), выполняющая смену слайдов.
    interval = window.setInterval(animate, sliderInterval);
  }



$(window).resize(function() {  
  slideWidth = thisEl.width();
  resized=true;
 }).resize()

  function animate(){
   if (resized) {
    //если поменялись размеры окна слайдера, то пересчитываем отступ слайдеров и меняем их ширину.
    var widthslider=slider_item.width(); //старая ширина слайдеов
    var numslider=parseInt(-margin/widthslider); //номер текущего слайдера
    slider_item.css('width',slideWidth); //меняем ширину слайдеров
    margin = -slideWidth * numslider; //считаем смещение слайдеров слева
    slider.css('margin-left', margin); //меняем смещение слайдов слева
    resized=false;
  }
    if (margin==-slideCount*slideWidth-slideWidth){     // Если слайдер дошел до конца
      slider.css({'marginLeft':-slideWidth});           // то блок .slider возвращается в начальное положение
      margin=-slideWidth*2;
    }else if(margin==0 && course==-1){                  // Если слайдер находится в начале и нажата кнопка "назад"
      slider.css({'marginLeft':-slideWidth*slideCount});// то блок .slider перемещается в конечное положение
      margin=-slideWidth*slideCount+slideWidth;
    }else{                                              // Если условия выше не сработали,
    margin = margin - slideWidth*(course);              // значение margin устанавливается для показа следующего слайда
    }
    slider.animate({'marginLeft':margin},animateTime);  // Блок .slider смещается влево на 1 слайд.
  }
 
  function sliderStop(){

    window.clearInterval(interval);                     // Функция преостанавливающая работу слайдера 
  }
 
  $(settings.prevBtn).click(function() {                               // Нажата кнопка "назад"
    if (slider.is(':animated')) { return false; }       // Если не происходит анимация
    var course2 = course;                               // Временная переменная для хранения значения course
    course = -1;                                        // Устанавливается направление слайдера справа налево
    animate();                                          // Вызов функции animate()
    course = course2 ;                                  // Переменная course принимает первоначальное значение
  });
  $(settings.nextBtn).click(function() {                               // Нажата кнопка "назад"
    if (slider.is(':animated')) { return false; }       // Если не происходит анимация
    var course2 = course;                               // Временная переменная для хранения значения course
    course = 1;                                         // Устанавливается направление слайдера справа налево
    animate();                                          // Вызов функции animate()
    course = course2 ;                                  // Переменная course принимает первоначальное значение
  });
 
  slider.add(next).add(prev).hover(function() {         // Если курсор мыши в пределах слайдера
    sliderStop();                                       // Вызывается функция sliderStop() для приостановки работы слайдера
  }, nextSlide);                                        // Когда курсор уходит со слайдера, анимация возобновляется.
 
  nextSlide();                                          // Вызов функции nextSlide()

})

};


})(jQuery)



$( document ).ready(function() {

$('.slider_wrapper').simpleSlider({
  sliderInterval: 2000,                              
    animateTime: 1000,                               
});

});
```

```css
.slider_wrapper{
  max-width:1000px;
  overflow:hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.slider_content{
  position:relative;
  width: 10000px;
}
.item {
 float: left;
}

.item img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider_wrapper">
  <div class="slider_content">

    <div class="item"> 
     <img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/maxresdefault-2-6.jpg" alt="" /> 
    </div>

    <div class="item">  
     <img src="https://cdni.rt.com/russian/images/2017.04/article/58fe599bc3618843468b47c1.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>

    <div class="item">  
     <img src="https://cdn2.img.sputnik-georgia.com/images/23488/54/234885475.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>

  <div class="item"> 
     <img src="https://i2.rozetka.ua/goods/4684342/41683632_images_4684342448.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>

    <div class="item">  
     <img src="https://thewire.in/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/space-1728314_1920.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При вызове плагина передаем еще один параметр `stopSlider`, который отвечает за остановку слайдера

```
$('.slider_wrapper').simpleSlider({
  stopSlider: true,
  sliderInterval: 2000,                              
  animateTime: 1000,                               
});
```

Затем в объект `settings` заводим дефолтное значение остановки слайдера

```
var settings = {
  stopSlider: false;
  sliderInterval: 2000,                              
  animateTime: 1000,                               
  course: 1,
  nextBtn: '.nextBtn',
  prevBtn: '.prevBtn',      
};
```

И следовательно в функции вызова пишем

```
slider.add(next).add(prev).hover(function() {
  if (settings.stopSlider) {
    sliderStop();
  }       
});
```

Comment: теперь остановка не работает, но при наведении на слайдер он ускоряется

Comment: а вот так всё норм   if (settings.stopSlider) {
  slider.add(next).add(prev).hover(function() {        
    sliderStop();                                         
  }, nextSlide);                                        
 }       Спасибо большое за помощь !

Comment: @Dio я не очень понимаю про что вы, но я немного изменил функцию остановки, посмотрите https://jsfiddle.net/w7b1k83f/

Comment: @Dio да, я именно это и сделал. Только вы вместо вот этого `slider.add(next).add(prev).hover` можете писать вот это `$('.slider_content').hover`